# Most exchange sites are out of private beta in 7 days. Why are we still in private beta?

Tags: discussion

I have read around that most exchange sites are in private beta for 7 days (sometimes a little longer) before going into a public beta. This is at the discretion of the Stack Exchange team, and so nobody can say for sure when exactly that will be.

The requirement, is that there needs to be enough quality content prior to going public.

**So, now what?**

That makes sense, but since we're now at almost twice the normal private beta length (13 days) it seems like something is missing in the eyes of the decision makers, but what?

How do we know what needs to be improved before the site can go into a public beta? Are there not enough questions? Are the questions too poor quality? Are the terms not refined enough? Are there not enough answers per question?

For those of us  hanging around in the private beta trying to boost the sites content, what are we lacking?

I'm am going on the assumption that since we didn't move to a public beta a week ago that something needs improving, but what?

Answer (score 7):

The current length of private beta seems to be 3 weeks, based on Robert's answer [here](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/108/52).

> As we approach the end of the private beta (**about three weeks after launch**),

(emphasis added)

So, based on that, we're right in the middle section.

As an example, [Retrocomputing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94441/retrocomputing), a site just ahead of us just went into public beta *today*, on their 20th day. So if we follow their pattern, we've got another week to go.

Similarly, [Language Learning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning) has been in beta for 34 days and went public 13 days ago, meaning they were in private beta for 21 days.

Comment: Oh, okay. I was going on [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158144/where-can-i-see-how-long-a-site-is-will-remain-in-private-beta)

Comment: Yeah, that question is 3.5 years old... and the beta/graduation system has gone through a lot of updating since then.